# Intersection angle of two points to sphere

Tags: calculus, 3d

I am attempting to find the $2$ intersection angles of $2$ 3d points and a sphere. Call the sphere $S$. It has a position, let's say $(3,3,3)$ and a radius, $2$. I then have two points, $A$ and $B$, say at $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,3,3)$ respectively. I know that one of the points is on the surface of the sphere, and I know that there will be $2$ angles representing the $x$ and $y$ rotation from the surface to the point. Thanks in advance for any help, I have had trouble finding anything on the subject.

Comment: When you say the sphere has a position, does that refer to the center of the sphere?

Comment: Am I interpreting this question correctly: if we let P be a plane through the point A tangent to the sphere, you're looking for the angle between the line segment AB and P, and the angle between the projection of AB onto P and "north" (the projection of (0,0,1) onto P).

Comment: Bsplitter: Yes, that is what I meant. Apologies for no tv clarifying.

Comment: TomKern: Yes, that is what I meant. Apologies for not being clearer.